# Location path security not working

Tags: asp.net, security

I have the following setup, but when I access the ManageContacts.aspx (from IIS express), it does not point me to the login.aspx, did I do anything wrong ? Simple password are for illustration purpose only.

```
<location path="~/ManageContacts.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="admin"/>
      </authorization>

      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login">
          <credentials>
            <user name="admin" password="123456"/>
          </credentials>
        </forms>
      </authentication>

    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: try like this ,  `path="ManageContacts.aspx"` without ~ sign.

Comment: Did that, and it says " It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
"

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginurl="Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="ManageContacts.aspx">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="admin" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location></configuration>
```